# When to use completely separate model for certain types of data?

Tags: variance, feature-selection, overfitting

This is a general question about using completely separate models for certain types of data.

Say I have data on people and I want to predict their income at a certain age.  I want to maximize the accuracy of the predictions.

When I lump all of the data together (including the feature for gender), the model has a certain level of performance.  But then, when I build separate models for men and women, the overall performance increases *significantly*.

My question is:  When is it appropriate to build separate models, splitting the data on a certain feature like this?  I haven't seen it done too much in the literature, and I often wonder why.

Is it because of interpretability?  or is it because of overfitting?

And, is there a word for this technique of building separate models?

Comment: I would say that it's appropriate to build separate models when you have separate questions you'd like to answer, which cannot be addressed by a single model. Why have you chosen to build two models rather than one model that uses gender as a predictor?

Comment: Because it performs better.  I editted that into my question.

Comment: What is your model intended to investigate? Whatever it is, if you were intending to use gender as a predictor, removing gender as an explicit part of your model and instead using it as an implicit part of two discrete models damages your ability to determine gender's effect on the outcome. If all you are interested in is predictivity, that's not a big deal. If you are interested in making any inferences about how your predictors are related to the outcome variable it's a bigger problem.

Comment: When you say "separate models" what do you mean? Are the two gender-specific models basically the same -- you copied your formula into each and removed `gender` -- or are you using different predictor variables in each? Also, how many samples do you have for males and for females?

Comment: I mean, I treat it like two separate datasets.  Then, for each men/women dataset, I choose a model, and then train, test, cross-validate to optimize the hyperparameters completely separately.  Does that make sense?

Comment: How does the number of samples for males and females affect this?

Comment: @Upper_Case, how does it damage my ability to make inferences about how the predictors affect the outcome??

Comment: There are a couple of ways. First, by excluding gender as a predictor, you can't obtain a beta for it and so can't estimate the impact of gender specifically on income in your model. Second, if you think that gender has an effect on income but don't include it explicitly in your models, then the models are incomplete. The main effects you find for your other predictors will (likely) be different than if gender were included. You also can't investigate interactions of gender with other variables, which often matter with income.

Comment: Third, it can be difficult to directly compare two different models which make different conditional assumptions. Fourth, by splitting your data set you reduce the number of observations informing each model, and if your n drops too low you'll have all sorts of issues (I've no idea if your n is sufficient for your purposes or not, but it can happen). Again, if you are tuning your models for predictivity the inference piece might not be as important for you.

Comment: Okay, @Upper_Case, these are good points.  Can you combine into an answer please?  I understand your points about interpretability and inference, but I would only use this technique if I were solely interested in performance.

Answer (score 3):

The process you just described is very similar to the approach a model like a random forest might take.  If your sole goal is predictive accuracy, you should definitely try a random forest.

In general, it's a bad idea to split your data and model on each subset.  Its better to find a way to better represent the subsets to the model, perhaps by using a random forest, or perhaps by adding an interaction between gender and age.

Assuming you're using a linear model, I suspect the interaction approach will yield better results than the "subsets" approach you are already using, because it lets the model learn an overall effect of age on income and a modification of that effect for male vs female.

In R, this is the difference between `lm(income ~ age + gender)` and  `lm(income ~ age * gender)`